# Is this the right way to optimize memory usage?

Tags: c, memory-management

My objective is to optimize memory usage... I've never seen it in any tutorial which leads me to think that this isn't the right way to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Player {
    char* username;
    int hp;
    int mp;
};

int main(void) {
    struct Player test, *p = &test;
    p->username = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", p->username);
    p->username = realloc(p->username, (strlen(p->username) + 1) * sizeof(char));   
    printf("%s", p->username);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",` which is basically a `gets()` in `scanf`'s clothing, is almost never right.

Comment: thanks for the remark, i usually use fgets

Comment: The downside is that you might fragment the available memory if you do it a lot. Also, there might be a minimum block size that is allocated, say 16 bytes or 1024 bytes or whatever, making it wasted effort. I would input into a generous local string (that will vanish on function exit) and allocate memory in the struct one time only, and copy the string (see `strdup()` function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> right way to optimize memory usage?

Temporary re-used buffers can often be generousness and fixed in size.

Allocating the right-size amount for memory makes sense for member `.username` for code could be for millions of `struct Player`.

IOWs, use allocation for the variable size aspects of code.  If `struct Player` was for 2-player chess, a `char username[50]` size makes sense.  For a multi-player universe, `char *` makes sense.

---

Rather than call `*alloc()` twice consider a single right-sized call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Reasonable upper bound
#define USERNAME_SIZEMAX 50

struct Player {
  char* username;
  int hp;
  int mp;
};

int main(void) {
  puts("Enter user name");
  // Recommend 2x - useful for leading/trailing spaces & detecting excessive long inputs.
  char buf[USERNAME_SIZEMAX * 50];

  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    puts("No input");
  } else {
    trim(buf); // TBD code to lop off leading/trailing spaces
    if (!valid_name(buf)) {  // TBD code to validate the `name`
      printf("Bad input \"%s\"\n", buf);
    } else {
      struct Player test = { 0 }; // fully populate
      test.username = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);
      // Maybe add NULL check here
      strcpy(test.username, buf);
      // Oh happy day!
      printf("%s", p->username);
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
  }
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: -so like this, username will exactly get the amount of storage needed? 
-why it doesn't make sense to use this for only 2 player?
-when you did `test.username = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);` you allocated the ammount of bytes needed for a char array so lets say the input was 20 char it will allocate 21 byte but if the input was 10 integers this will take 20 byte but that function will malloc will allocate only 1 byte...not sure if my question was clear here

Comment: @Mohamed "but if the input was 10 integers this will take 20 byte" is unclear.  User input is _only_ characters.  `"1234\n"` is 5 characters.  `"Moha\n"` is 5 characters.  `" ! @\n"` is 5 characters.

Comment: user input should be only characters but if the user for whatever reason decided to input integers it will create a problem, so i think I must check first that the entry is only made by characters

Comment: @Mohamed "if the user for whatever reason decided to input integers", --> Let us look at a lower level.  User cannot input _integers_.   User can enter 3 characters like `'4'`, `'2'` and `'\n'`.   `fgets()` will read as 3 _characters_ and form a _string_ of `'4'`, `'2'`, `'\n'` and append a `'\0'`.  Even if code used `scanf("%d", &x)`, the 3 character input is read as 3 _characters_ and converted to an `int` 42. That 42 is saved at `x`. Code cannot control user input.   There is no magic power to prevent  any typing. Code can take that text input and convert to `int`, `double`, _strings_, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Some tips:

a) the example code is too small to matter

b) never use `malloc()` for something that you will always want one of. Instead, pre-allocate (e.g. as a global variable) or (if it's small enough) use a local variable to avoid the overhead of `malloc()`. E.g.:

```
int main(void) {
    struct Player test, *p = &test;
    char userName[50];
    p->username = userName;
```

c) Don't spread data all over the place. You want all the data in the same place (in the least number of cache lines, with pieces of data that are used at the same time as close to each other as possible). One way to do that is to combine multiple items. E.g.:

```
struct Player {
    char username[50];
    int hp;
    int mp;
};

int main(void) {
    struct Player test, *p = &test;
```

d) If something takes (at most) 50 chars of memory; don't bother using `realloc()` to waste CPU time and potentially waste more memory. Don't forget that the internal code for `malloc()` and `realloc()` will add meta-data to each allocated piece of memory that is likely to cost an extra 16 bytes or more.

In general; for performance, `malloc()` and `realloc()` (and `new()` and ...) should be completely avoided (especially for larger programs). They spread data "randomly" everywhere and destroy any hope of getting good locality (which is important for minimising multiple very expensive things - cache misses, TLB misses, page faults, swap space usage, ...).

Note: `scanf()` and `gets()` should also be banned. They provide no way to prevent buffer overflows (e.g. the user providing more than 50 characters when there's only enough memory allocated for 50 characters, for the purpose of deliberately trashing/corrupting other data), which results in huge gaping security holes.

Comment: @Brendan function `scanf()` does provide a way to prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes, technically it has "optional support" that people forget to use.

Comment: _ for performance, malloc() and realloc() (and new() and ...) should be completely avoided_ When should/do you recommend me to use them? 
Another thing, when i declat `char test[50]` and input integers in it, will integers take 2 byte as usual or 1 byte as a char?

Comment: @Mohamed: There's always a compromise between performance and developer time. Use things like `malloc()` when developer time is more important than performance. Alternatives depend on the specific scenario (maybe use local variables, maybe use something like "objstacks", maybe allocate an array and then manage array entries, maybe implement your own heap that supports "memory pools", ...).